# Why won't the Python Tkinter Canvas Scroll?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, magic-mouse

Why can't I get the python tkinter canvas to respond to the vertical and horizontal swiping/scrolling of Apple's Magic Mouse? The scrollbars for the canvas work properly (meaning the horizontal bar works when I swipe/scroll horizontally on the mouse but not when I swipe/scroll vertically, and the vertical scrollbar moves when I swipe/scroll vertically but doesn't react to any horizontal swiping/scrolling motion), but the canvas doesn't react to any swiping/scrolling of the mouse.

Here is my example/test code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
root = Tk()

h = Scrollbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL)
v = Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL)
canvas = Canvas(root, scrollregion=(0, 0, 1000, 1000), yscrollcommand=v.set, xscrollcommand=h.set)
h['command'] = canvas.xview
v['command'] = canvas.yview
theImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('example.png')) #Assume a very large image
canvas.create_image(0,0,image=theImage, anchor='nw')
canvas.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
h.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(W,E))
v.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=(N,S))
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.mainloop()
```

I'm a total novice when it comes to both Python and tkinter, but I feel like this should be really simple and obvious (or at least do-able). And yet I've looked all over and still can't find the answer (though I might be searching using the wrong jargon).

What does it take to make the canvas react to scrolling/swiping inputs from the Magic Mouse like the scrollbars do already?

Edit: I'm using Python 3.4, Tkinter 8.5.18, Mac OS X 10.9.5, and an Apple Magic Mouse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the magic mouse's scroll and swipe inputs work like the scrolling regions on a standard trackpad, you need to bind the `<MouseWheel>` and `<Shift-MouseWheel>` events.

First the code, then some notes.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def on_vertical(event):
    canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * event.delta, 'units')

def on_horizontal(event):
    canvas.xview_scroll(-1 * event.delta, 'units')

root = Tk()
h = Scrollbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL)
v = Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL)
canvas = Canvas(root, scrollregion=(0, 0, 1000, 1000), yscrollcommand=v.set, xscrollcommand=h.set)
h['command'] = canvas.xview
v['command'] = canvas.yview
theImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('img'))
canvas.create_image(0,0,image=theImage, anchor='nw')
canvas.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))

canvas.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', on_vertical)
canvas.bind_all('<Shift-MouseWheel>', on_horizontal)

h.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(W,E))
v.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=(N,S))
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.mainloop()
```

As you can see there are only 2 changes.

1. There are two callback functions to handle the scroll events `on_vertical` and `on_horizontal`
2. The canvas `<MouseWheel>` and `<Shift-MouseWheel>` events are bound to `on_vertical` and `on_horizontal` respectively.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works, though the deltas were going the wrong way at first. But that was easily fixed by sticking a negative sign in front of the event.delta in the callback functions.

Comment: Yep, sorry about that, I'm on Windows, so the wheel delta has to be divided by 120 and inverted, and when I got rid of the division I accidentally got rid of the negation. I updated the code to fix the bug. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: It doesn't work on the newest high sierra. I get `UnicodeDecodeError`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ntk](https://ntk.readthedocs.io) Canvas to create a scroll able Canvas, by default it works on mouse scroll, but if you create a ntk Scrollbar widget, and assign it to canvas, you are good to go.

ntk works on top of tkinter, to install it from pypi with pip

```
pip install ntk
```

use ntk widgets to get awesome design.

```
from ntk import Tk, Canvas, Scrollbar

def main():
    root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root)

    root.mainloop()    

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

this canvas is scroll able by mouse scroll, but if you want to set a bar with it, you can create a scroll bar widget and pass this canvas object as second param

```
scroll = Scrollbar(root, canvas)
```

you can change scroll able area from canvas by configure or pass it when canvas is creating

```
canvas = Canvas(root, scrollregion=[0,0,100,50]) # [x1, y1, x2, y2]
```

or configure it by

```
canvas.config(scrollregion=[0,0,100,50])
```

welcome to beautiful design in less code, happy codding.